# When is a proper map between smooth varieties a submersion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a submersion between projective manifolds. Then $Rf^i_*(\mathbb{C}_X)$ are local systems on $X$, for all $i$.

My question is whether the converse is true. More precisely, let $f: X\to Y$ be a holomorphic map between projective manifolds. Suppose that for all $i$, $Rf^i_*(\mathbb{C}_X)$ are global local systems on $X$. Is $f$ necessarily a submersion?

If this is not true, what is a counter-example?

Comment: Isn't that already false for an isotrivial family of elliptic curves specializing to a double fiber (whose reduced curve is the isogenous quotient of the elliptic curve by a 2-torsion translation)?  Do you want to instead use for coefficients some torsion group that can detect such translations?

Comment: Jason, thank you for the simple and nice example! This is indeed the counter-example I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am just posting my comment above as an answer.  There are counterexamples that depend on the fact that the divisible coefficient sheaf $\mathbb{C}_X$ (for the analytic topology, presumably) does not detect certain torsion phenomena.  Begin with a smooth, projective, geometrically integral curve $E$ of genus $1$ and a nontrivial $2$-torsion translation $\tau:E\to E$.  Form $Z=E\times \mathbb{A}^1$.  Let a cyclic group $G$ of order $2$ act diagonally on $Z$ via $\tau$ on $E$ and via $t\mapsto -t$ on $\mathbb{A}^1$.  Let $X$ be $Z/G$, and let $Y$ be $\mathbb{A}^1/G$.  Let $f:X\to Y$ be the unique morphism induced by the projection $\text{pr}_2:E\times \mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1$.  Then $f_*\mathbb{C}_X$ is $\mathbb{C}_Y$, $R^2f_*\mathbb{C}_X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}_Y$, and $R^1f_*\mathbb{C}_X$ is also a localy system isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}_Y^{\oplus 2}$.  It is the last one that is a bit more delicate, since for every $y \in Y$ other than the origin, for the fiber $X_y=f^{-1}(\{y\})$, the map on homology, $$H_1(X_y;\mathbb{Z})\to H_1(X;\mathbb{Z}),$$ is *not* an isomorphism.  It is injective and the image is an index $2$ subgroup.  However, once we tensor with the divisible group $\mathbb{C}$, the induced map is an isomorphism.  To say it differently, $R^1f_*\mu_2$ is not a local system.

Comment: Jason, thank you for the detailed construction and explanation. Now, I wonder, as you mentioned earlier, whether $Rf_*^i(\mathbb{Z})$ and $Rf_*^i(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ are all local systems implies that $f$ is a submersion.